# What is your course or what was your course?

Tags: tense

Which is grammatically correct?

> What is your course <s>back then</s>?

or

> What was your course back then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the **Present Simple** with **"back then"**. Only **"What was your course back then?"** is correct.

**"Back then"** is an expression you can use in order to refer to a specific period of time in the past. So are **"at that (the) time"** and **"in those (the) days"**. However, you can use **"at that (the) time"** with the future tenses.

Comment: Thanks mates!  If the time is in the past, you should use past tense, as well.

Comment: Presumably it should be _"your"_, not _"you"_? ("What was **your** course back then?")

Comment: **"What was your course back then?"** is correct.